# What is the typeof of a QuerySnapshot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

With firebase, you can get documents in a collection like this:  `const collectionData = await collectionPath.get();`
using collectionData, you can loop with:

```
collectionData.forEach(doc=>{ // doc here is a document, and we can get data with doc.data()});
```

The above code makes collectionData behave like an array of documents. However, you can still treat it like an object by calling things like size? e.g `collectionData.size` will return the size of items in there.

My question is, what data type is a QuerySnapshot or the data returned by calling .get() on a firebase reference?

Comment: Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot Code: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/cdada6c68f9740d13dd6674bcb658e28e68253b6/packages/firestore/src/api/snapshot.ts#L378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) is a regular JS object with a few custom methods in it, and one of them is the `forEach` method that essentially works as a proxy, kind of shortcut, to the actual `docs.forEach` array method.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/cdada6c68f9740d13dd6674bcb658e28e68253b6/packages/firestore/src/api/snapshot.ts#L432-L452

Comment: this makes sense now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) has the `docs` field which represents an array of `QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>>` so you could call `QuerySnapshot.docs.length` to see the size of the collection.

For the collectionData questions, could you post more of your example code? Which module is this using (e.g. `@firebase/firestore`)?